# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, web

> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect
>   syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.

**here is my code**

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Protected Sub btnEdit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnEdit.Click
    If (IsPostBack) Then
        If (Not Session("Language_ID") = Nothing) Then

            cn.Open()

            Dim cmdEdit As New SqlCommand("UPDATE [tblDefault] SET [Language] = @lang, [Title1] = @title1," & _
                                          "[Details1]=@detail1,[Details2]=@detail2," & _
                                          "[Title3] = @title3, [Details3] = @detail3, [Welcome] = @wel," & _
                                          "WHERE [LangID] = @langid", cn)
            With cmdEdit.Parameters
                .Add("@langid", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = Val(Session("Language_ID").ToString)
                .Add("@lang", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = ddlLang.SelectedValue
                .Add("@title1", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtTitle1.Text
                .Add("@detail1", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = CkeditorDetail1.Text
                .Add("@title2", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtTitle2.Text
                .Add("@detail2", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = CkeditorDetail2.Text
                .Add("@title3", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtTitle3.Text
                .Add("@detail3", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = CkeditorDetail3.Text
                .Add("@wel", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtWel.Text
            End With

            cmdEdit.Connection = cn
            cmdEdit.ExecuteNonQuery()

            cn.Close()

            Response.Redirect("admin_default.aspx")

        Else
            Response.Redirect("admin_default.aspx")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `,` after `@wel,`:

```
 "[Title3] = @title3, [Details3] = @detail3, [Welcome] = @wel," & _
```

Should be:

```
"[Title3] = @title3, [Details3] = @detail3, [Welcome] = @wel " & _
```